# Why does my code work with underscore.js but not when I use Ramda.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, ramda.js

I am new to Javascript, I am doing a coding challenge to learn more about the language.  This is not school related or anything like that, totally for my own personal growth.  Here is the challenge:

> Return the sum of all odd Fibonacci numbers up to and including the
>   passed number if it is a Fibonacci number.

I have spent the past 2 evenings working on solving this challenge.  When I run my code using underscore.js it works.  When I use Ramda.js it says `NaN`.  I would think both would return `NaN`.  I'm very surprised that I can get the correct answer from one and not the other.   Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

```
var R = require('ramda');

function sumFibs(num) {
var fib_Arr = [];
var new_Arr = [];
var total = 0;
// I use this to tell if the fib num is greater than 2
var the_Bit = "false";
// This is used to keep track of when to stop the loop
var fib_Num = 0;

// THIS WORKS FROM HERE
// This loop generates a list of fibonacci numbers then pushes them to the    fib_Arr
for(var i = 0; total < num; i++){
if (i < 1){
  fib_Arr.push(0);

}
else if (i === 1){
  fib_Arr.push(i);
  fib_Arr.push(1);
}
else if (i === 2){
  fib_Arr.push(2);
  the_Bit = "true";
}
else if (the_Bit === "true"){
  temp_Arr = R.last(fib_Arr,2);
  temp_Arr = temp_Arr[0] + temp_Arr[1];
  fib_Arr.push(temp_Arr);
  total = R.last(fib_Arr);
}
// Generating the fib Array works TO HERE!!!!
}

// console.log(fib_Arr); // Print out the generated fibonacci array
// if last Array element is greater than the original in
 var last_Element = R.last(fib_Arr);
if (last_Element > num){
  console.log("The last element of the array is bigger!");
  fib_Arr.splice(-1,1); // This removes the last item from the array if it is  larger than the original num input
 }

// This loop removes all of the EVEN fibonacci numbers and leaves all of the ODD numbers
  for (var j = 0; j < fib_Arr.length; j++){
    if (fib_Arr[j] % 2 !== 0){
      new_Arr.push((fib_Arr[j]));
    }
  }

// This checks if the original input num was a
    if (num % 2 !== 0){
    new_Arr.push(num);
    }
    else{
      console.log("The original num was not a Fibonacci number!");
    }
  // if last Array element is the same as the original input num
    var last = R.last(fib_Arr);
  if (last === num){
   console.log("Removing the last element of the array!");
    new_Arr.splice(-1,1); // This removes the last item from the array if it is the same as the original num input
  }

// Now to add all of the numbers up :-)
  for (var k = 0; k < new_Arr.length; k++){
    console.log("This is fib_Num: " + fib_Num);
    // console.log(fib_N`);
    fib_Num = fib_Num += new_Arr[k];
  }
  return fib_Num;
}
// TEST CASES:
// console.log(sumFibs(75025)); //.to.equal(135721);
console.log(sumFibs(75024)); //.to.equal(60696);
```

Comment: What if you take debugger and debug it? Just go through every line and check if the runtime state is as you would expect.

Comment: `R.last(fib_Arr,2)`? I don't see the docs mentioning that `last` takes a second argument.

Comment: Why do you need anything like either Ramda or Underscore to do this? It's an extremely simple problem, requiring only a single simple `for` loop to add up the sequence of values which you can compute with a single simple addition operation on each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem on these lines :

```
temp_Arr = R.last(fib_Arr,2);
temp_Arr = temp_Arr[0] + temp_Arr[1];
```

Besides the fact that `R.last` does not take a second argument (that will not fail though), you are using `temp_arr` as an array, when it is a number. Therefore, `temp_arr` gets a `NaN` value.

You are probably looking for `R.take` (combined with `R.reverse`) or `R.slice`.

---

**By changing :**

```
temp_Arr = R.last(fib_Arr,2);
```

**with :**

```
temp_Arr = R.take(2, R.reverse(fib_Arr));
```

**or with :**

```
temp_Arr = R.slice(fib_Arr.length - 2, fib_Arr.length)(fib_Arr);
```

**or with (bonus play with a reduce from the right) :**

```
temp_Arr = R.reduceRight(function(arr, elem) { 
    return arr.length < 2 ? [elem].concat(arr) : arr;
}, [])(fib_Arr);
```

**We get :**

```
sumFibs(75024) === 60696
```

Comment: Thanks so much Michael!  I really appreciate the detailed insight and answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the record, here's how you do this problem:

```
function fibSumTo(n) {
  var f1 = 1, f2 = 1, sum = 1, t;
  while (f2 <= n) {
    if (f2 & 1) sum += f2;
    t = f1 + f2;
    f1 = f2;
    f2 = t;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

There's really no need for any sort of library because there's really no need for any sort of data structure.

Comment: Good point, as this solution is the one that does not add superfluous structures and keep the only necessary for computing the numbers of the Fibonacci sequence. But I believe that OP is more about trying popular JS libraries, than making the optimal algorithm.

Comment: Man!! I really over complicated this code challenge...I seem to over analyze coding issues :-(  Thanks for showing me how to solve the problem with using a library!

Answer (score -1):

```
var _ = require('underscore');function sumUpFibs (number){
arr_of_fibs = [1,1];
current = 1; //cursor for previous location
while (true){
    var num = arr_of_fibs[current] + arr_of_fibs[current - 1];
    if (num <= number) {
        arr_of_fibs.push(num);
        current++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
console.log(arr_of_fibs);
var total = 0;
_.each(arr_of_fibs, function(fib){
    total += fib;
})
return total;}console.log(sumUpFibs(75025));
```

This may be a better implementation... Though I know you're just starting so I don't want to come off as mean : D.... Also, maybe check your test cases too.

Comment: The point was to use [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/), not underscore. Also, why are you using global variables in your function (by omitting the `var` keyword, you are creating global variables). Finally, your formatting is pretty bad. You should post nicely formatted code on SO.

Comment: No reason to criticize. I do not get, for the life of me, why it seems like everyone on this site is a jerk? I tried to help. If it didn't help, just ignore it.